# Rails find_or_initialize_by with joins ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models

```
users (id, name, ...)
authorizations (id, provider, provider_uid, user_id,...)
```

> users has_many authorizations

Now when i have to login via facebook i need to check if the `provider_uid` is preset if not create a new one.

```
user = User.joins(:authorizations).find_or_initialize_by(
      authorizations: {
        provider: 'facebook',
        provider_uid: provider_uid
      }
    )
```

**Error**

> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch - Authorization(#70336918074440)
>   expected, got Array(#70336893054160):

Comment: It seems you have to provide single object and you are providing array

Comment: What is `influencer_authorizations`?

Comment: sorry its `authorizations` changed the question. had simplified the models to make it easy

Comment: @Ansar in the joins. its getting back an array. but i need only 1. any way to specify that it to return only 1 join association

Comment: You are looking to create user or authorization? Because in above query you are just joining it with users table without passing any user_id?

Comment: Don't you want to do something like `User.joins(:authorizations).where("users.id = ?", params[:id])` ?

Comment: Yes you can like
has_one :authorizations , class_name: 'Authorizations ', conditions: '(provider: 'facebook')'

Comment: and use user = User.joins(:authorization).find_or_initialize_by(
      authorizations: {
        provider: 'facebook',
        provider_uid: provider_uid
      }
    )

Comment: @RSB A user can have multiple authorizations so i want to find the `user` based on the `authorizations` table record.

Comment: By doing that you are initializing a user object, is that correct?

Comment: @RSB yes. basically i am trying to find which user is trying to login. he can have twitter, facebook etc attached to one single user account. I wanna check if the user exists if it does wanna update the user token n log him in. If not create a new user n save him n his authorizations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `first_or_initialize` instead, both the scenarios are covered below

You can try this if you want to initialize a `user` object

```
user = User.joins(:authorizations).where("authorizations.provider = 'facebook' AND authorizations.provider_uid = ?", provider_uid).first_or_initialize
```

But, if you want to find or create authorization for an existing user, you can do this, you can use `first_or_initialize`

```
authorization = Authorization.where(user_id: user_id, provider: 'facebook', provider_uid: provider_uid).first_or_initialize
authorization.save if authorization.new_record?
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is it possible to have a quick chat here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114635/rails-associated-table-does-not-update

Comment: This is the problem am facing because of the above @RSB