# Rails Associated Table Does not update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, service-object

I have two models

```
influencers(id, first_name, ....)
influencer_authorizations(id, provider, provider_uid, oauth_token, ....)
```

> influencers has_many influencer_authorizations

I am trying to login or Sign the Influencer

```
  # 1. Check if the Token is Valid
  # 2. Check if the influencer has the authorization for that facebook_uid
  # 3. If no - then create a new influencer
  # 4. If yes - Then he is loging in. so update the token and log him in
```

But when a OLD user tries to login the OAuth Token is not getting updated

**Facebook Controller**

```
def create

    @facebook_login = FacebookClient.new(facebook_user_token)

    if @facebook_login.create
      render :show
    else
      render :error
    end

  end
```

**Facebook Client**

```
class FacebookClient
  def initialize(token)
    @token = token
    @client = Koala::Facebook::API.new(token)
  end

  attr_reader :influencer

  def create
    @influencer = new_or_existing_influencer

    save_influencer
  end

  def errors
    {
      facebook_error: @facebook_errors
    }
  end

  private

  attr_reader :client

  def new_or_existing_influencer
    influencer = Influencer.joins(:influencer_authorizations).where(
                        :influencer_authorizations => {
                          provider: 'facebook',
                          provider_uid: provider_uid
                        }
                      ).first_or_initialize
    influencer
  end

  def save_influencer
    set_influencer_details if @influencer.new_record?
    set_influencer_authorization_details if @influencer.new_record?

    @influencer.influencer_authorizations[0].oauth_token = @token if !influencer.new_record?

    @influencer.save
  end

  def set_influencer_details
    @influencer.assign_attributes(
        first_name: first_name,
        last_name: last_name,
        email: email,
        bio: bio,
        date_of_birth: birthday,
        gender: gender,
        location: location
    )
  end

  def set_influencer_authorization_details
    @influencer.influencer_authorizations.build(
        provider: 'facebook',
        provider_uid: provider_uid,
        oauth_token: @token,
        social_account: SocialAccount.friendly.find('facebook')
    )
  end

  def basic_information
    begin
       @basic_information ||= client.get_object("me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,name,bio,about,birthday,email,timezone,gender,location,hometown,currency,locale,devices")
     rescue Koala::Facebook::APIError => exc
       @facebook_errors = exc.message
    end
  end

  def provider_uid
    basic_information["id"]
  end

  def first_name
    basic_information["first_name"]
  end

  def last_name
    basic_information["last_name"]
  end

  def name
    basic_information["name"]
  end

  def email
    basic_information["email"]
  end

  def bio
    basic_information["bio"]
  end

  def location
    basic_information["location"].present? ? basic_information["location"]["name"] : ""
  end

  def birthday
    basic_information["birthday"].present? ? Date.strptime(basic_information["birthday"], "%m/%d/%Y") : ""
  end

  def gender
    basic_information["gender"].present? ? basic_information["gender"] : "not_specified"
  end

end
```

Just before saving on inspect the Oauth Token is set to `@influencer.influencer_authorizations[0].oauth_token`

Comment: Have you tried `@influencer.influencer_authorizations.update_attribute(oauth_token: @token)`?

Comment: @dan-klasson any specific reason you need to do that manually? `@influencer.influencer_authorizations[0].oauth_token = @token if !influencer.new_record?` would this not do the same?

Comment: @dan-klasson also when i try that i am getting `ArgumentError - wrong number of arguments`

Comment: I don't know. But I don't think that way is the way to do it. Actually, in my example I am missing a `.first`

Comment: My bad, needs to `(oauth_token, @token)`. http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute

Comment: damn this is so weird :P it now says `undefined local variable or method `oauth_token' for #` :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111487/discussion-between-dan-klasson-and-harsha-m-v).